# Adding class for child items by css?

Tags: html, css

This is my code for now.

I need to put 'text-center' class for each item by hands.

On the other hands, I can add `font-size:` all at once to each item

Is it possible to add `class` `text-center` all at once by `css`??

```
<div>
    <div class="itemSquare">
        <p class="text-center">item1</p>
        <p class="text-center">item2</p>
        <p class="text-center">item3</p>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.itemSquare > p{
    font-size:16px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: no ...............

Comment: Do you want to add the class ```text-center``` to all your paragraph elements that are inside the div with the class ```itemSquare```?

Comment: Why you need to put `text-center` for each `p`? You can just add it once on `.itemSquare`.

Answer (score 0):

There are CSS solutions as 'SASS' and 'LESS', which could provide you such functionality, however if you are running out of time, you may use this JavaScript code:

```
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    const paragraphElements = document.querySelectorAll('div[class=itemSquare] p');

    for (let index = 0; index < paragraphElements.length; index++)
    {
        const paragraph = paragraphElements[index];

        paragraph.classList.add('yourClassName')
    }
  });
```